# How to write injectable reusable code instead of hardcoding the authentication on every method

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, sharepoint, dependency-injection

I have a webapi which talks with Sharepoint to do tenant level operations, like listing site collections, creating sites, etc etc.

The web api methods works perfect, but however the authentication mechanism might change in the future, now the only way to create a modern site collection is via authenticated user and password, in the future they might enable app only authentication to create modern sites: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/34236700-ability-to-use-app-only-calls-to-create-modern-sit

The problem with my code, its that I have hardcoded the authentication line in every method of the webapi, and I would like to abstract that line in a way outside of the webapi class, that whenever Microsoft implements a different authentication mechanism, that I can easily change that class and not the web api methods one by one.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        //[Route("api/SiteCollections/CreateModernSite")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateModernSite([FromBody]NewSiteInformation model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)

            {
                var tenant = await TenantHelper.GetTenantAsync();
                using (var context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/tesmmodernsite1", "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "xxx"))
                {
                    try
                    {
```

Comment: Is this just a straight ASP.Net (core?) project? You can write your own authentication handlers which live outside of your controllers.

Comment: its asp.net web api, sharepoint references csom dlls are not compatible

Comment: the question is how to abstract this line ouf of each method:     using (var context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/tesmmodernsite1", "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "xxx"))

Comment: You should be able to reference csom, I did it in core.

Comment: ok, maybe that changed . in the  last 3 months, but thats not the question here

Comment: @LuisValencia It actually does, because then you can use `SharePointOnlineCredentials` which will correlate a username and password to perform your actions.

Comment: interesting! a pointer to more documentation? or samples